# Clang format for space around double colon (::)

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there a way for clang format to add space around double colon used between class name and member function like `class :: function`.

Also is there a way that there be no space at all.

---

Currently majority of the legacy code has the format `class :: function` but auto formatting changes it to `class ::function` (removes space after, keeps the space before). I want to keep consistency with the existing code when I reformat the code.

Comment: This would be an unusual formatting for `class::function`...

Comment: I know, but the legacy code is like that and when I auto-format the code, it changes all class :: function to class ::function.
It would be acceptable if it changed to class::function.

Comment: Maybe, it's worth to [edit] the reason for your requirement into the question to prevent (more or less) useless comments like mine... ;-)

Comment: Is it only for class name? what about <namespace>::<something>

Comment: The part I am editing only uses it for member function. I guess for namespaces it won't much of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no format option in Clang to add or preserve space after scope resolution operator (at least until version 10 whose options I checked).

Comment: Is there a reason for removing space after and not before? Actually I noticed it will remove if there are more than one spaces before the "::" always keeping one space, so I thought there should be some default option that cause that behavior.

Comment: @Saeid I don't know. You should maybe ask that from the authors of the formatter. Maybe no-one thought that someone might want to have spaces around that operator, and keeping the preceding space is incidental.